# Can I tell when recaptcha3 rejects a bot?

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I have implemented reCaptcha 3 (changed from 2), and I seem to be getting a few bots.  It's not has much bot traffic as a few years ago when I had nothing, but when I had recaptcha 2 I didn't get any bots.

I don't know if it's not working at all, or if only some are sneaking through.

I did the simple setup here:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#automatically_bind_the_challenge_to_a_button

How can I tell it if ever rejects anyone?  How do I test it?

Answer (score 0):

When you got the token，you can verify the token,
like here :
[Request to verify](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)

The Score (1.0 means very likely legitimate traffic while 0.0 means very likely non-legitimate traffic)

P.S. reCaptcha v3 does't auto block bot, you have to do something on the basis of score.